# summarize mutliple typings in one file

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, typescript-typings

My problem is, that I've some older Angular 1 projects, where I use Ui-Router in version 0.2.8 and I want to upgrade to the newest RC release which is no longer available with NuGet

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld

but in my Project I've no npm or bower, its a Visual Studio project where I use NuGet so far and I've no chance to use npm at the moment.

when I get the ui-router from npm in an new project, I see all the Typing files. Is it possible to summarize them all in one file? Is there a tool out there that can do this? Or what would be the best Solution for my problem?

Comment: Why can't you leave those files there? That's how TS works by default looking for type definitions in the package folder.

Comment: @vintem when it would be so easy :-) the main problem is the current d.ts files are made for npm and require or import and thats not working on a good old javaScript Project.